# Saving the values of a dynamically changing array into a pointer C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am trying to solve this problem. I am a beginner in C.

```
                        uint8_t *instrumentStringsCount;
instrumentStringsCount = malloc(sizeof(uint8_t));
dbGettingStringsNumbers(instrumentStringsCount, familyID);
uint8_t sizeCount = instrumentStringsCount[0];
uint8_t i = 0;

char stringTransferArray[10];
char *mainArray[sizeCount];

while(i < sizeCount)
{
    sprintf(stringTransferArray, "%d strings", instrumentStringsCount[i+1]);
    mainArray[i]= stringTransferArray;
    i++;
}
```

The thing is that stringTransferArray is dynamically changing (instrumentStringsCount: being fetched from the db). So the values of the pointers are always being changed to the last value in the array. 
I know the reason for that; however, I just need a way to solve this.

Thanks for your efforts

Comment: I sure hope the number in `instrumentStringsCount[i+1]` is always a single digit. Or you will write out of bounds in that `sprintf` call.

Comment: As for your problem, there are functions to duplicate strings. It's not really standardized in the C specification, but I know of no platform that doesn't have a `strdup` function.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude the number in instrumentStringsCount is always a single digit

Answer (score 0):

> My problem is in this line: mainArray[i]= stringTransferArray; the stringTransferArray is changing and when that happens, all the values of the mainArray show the last value associated with stringTransferArray

As for your problem, there are functions to duplicate strings. It's not really standardized in the C specification, but I know of no platform that doesn't have a `strdup` function.
                    – Some programmer dude

Answer (score -1):

`sizeof(uint8_t)` is likely to be 1 byte. And that is not enough for `instrumentStringsCount` (so you are `malloc`-ing a too small memory zone, which will give you [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) when using later `instrumentStringsCount[i+1]`, a typical case of [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior); you really should [**be *very* scared**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25636788/841108)). You probably want to keep in another variable the allocated size (and you should have a *convention* to know the allocated size), and you should test against failure of `malloc` so code:

```
size_t instrumentStringSize = 24;
uint8_t *instrumentStringsCount = malloc(instrumentStringSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
if (!instrumentStringsCount) { perror("malloc"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); };
```

You might want to also keep the *used length* of your buffer.

At some times in your program, you may want to grow your `instrumentStringsCount` memory zone. Since you don't want to call `realloc` or `malloc` at every round, you probably should grow the size with e.g. an affine function:

```
size_t newsize = 4*instrumentStringSize/3+ 10;
uint8_t* newStringsCount = malloc(newsize * sizeof(uint8_t));
```

etc  (e.g. test against failure of `malloc` and copy using `memcpy` the old memory zone into the new one, etc...).

At last, you should use [snprintf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf) (and give the actual size of the buffer) instead of `sprintf` (because you [*really* want](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25636753/is-segmentation-fault-actual-undefined-behavior-when-we-refer-to-a-non-static-da/25636788#25636788) to avoid [buffer overflow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow) and other [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

If on Linux, compile with all warnings & debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`). The [instrumentation options of `gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) like `-fsanitize=address` and other sanitizers would also be helpful. Then use the `gdb` debugger & [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I guess you did not understand my question. My problem is in this line: mainArray[i]= stringTransferArray; the stringTransferArray is changing and when that happens, all the values of the mainArray show the last value associated with stringTransferArray

Comment: No, you are `malloc`-ing a too small memory zone. That is UB. And **you should really be *very scared***.

Comment: I insist that you should be very scared and read more about undefined behavior.

Comment: Thank you for your concern but I just needed an answer for the above question. What I am dealing with is a very small unique particular case. I am not that concerned with that fact. However, do you have any way to solve my problem? Maybe using a different function?

Comment: Since your code has UB, the "I just need a way to solve this" question requires removing the undefined behavior (so using `malloc` *properly*, not wrongly).